how to get full version history of SharePoint list item from from begining
Additional environment details

"@pnp/sp": "^3.13.0", "react": "17.0.1",

"@microsoft/sp-core-library": "^1.17.1",

"@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "^1.17.1",

"@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "^1.17.1",

"@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "^1.17.1",

"@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "^1.17.1",


i am working with spfx with react.i need full version history of SharePoint list item from begining.
but pnp/js return version number 10.0 when history more then 50. please assist me for this issue.
export const getItemHistory = async (Id, LIST_NAME) => {
let queryParams = new GET_LIST_QUERY_PARAMS();
queryParams.selectProperties = ["*,Versions"];
queryParams.expandProperties = ["Versions"];

const assetResult = await getSPListItemById(
    LIST_NAME,
    queryParams.selectProperties,
    queryParams.expandProperties,
    Id
);

return assetResult;

}
